# Security : Role defined can be misused via url edit and changes. in ruby application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In this applicatin there are four roles,

role can get into unauthorized pages by editing the url ids and perform actions on available options with respect to the page, misleading to malfunctioning of the application.

any one have idea about this. Is it the problem of closing the session Or routes permition 
 problem ... 
thanks in advance

Comment: It has nothing to do with routing issues, it's a permissions issue and it's something you need to handle yourself. Perhaps using something like cancan? github.com/ryanb/cancan you can check if a role has permission to edit something in a before filter and if they don't, redirect them and give them some feedback

Answer (score 1):

Its nothing related to routes, you can restrict action access yourself with filters, i.e.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_access

  def secure_action_a
  end

  def secure_action_b
  end

  private

  def check_access
    case params[:action]
      when 'secure_action_a':
        redirect_to root_path, error: "Not Allowed" unless current_user.role == 'admin'
      when 'secure_action_b':
        redirect_to root_path, error: "Not Allowed" unless current_user.role == 'user'
    end
  end
end
```

and also on an action, you should verify that the user has access to the resource, so let's say that you have an action that shows a transaction to the user, and that he can only see his transactions, if you write a code like:

```
def transaction
  @transaction = Transaction.find(params[:id])
end
```

then you have a big issue, because anyone can start writting requests like "http://mywebsite.com/transaction/23" and see the transaction because there are not any filters on the current user, so you usually make sure that the user owns the resource

```
def transaction
  @transaction = current_user.transactions.find(params[:id])
end
```

or either

```
def transaction
  @transaction = Transaction.where(user_id: current_user.id, id: params[:id])
end
```

later you can advanced gems like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to control the access to the resources

finally, make sure to read the [rails security guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html)

Comment: cool, if my answer helped with the task, don't forget to accept my answer as a valid answer (so I can get more reputation and better jobs in the future :P), if you have any other question regarding the role restrictions, just let me know, but as I wrote, the rails security guide is a great guide to read about rails security and how to prevent a bad use of your website ;)

Comment: hey rorra .. this is ok but in one role lets take there are 2 manager both have diff employee .my problem  is 1st manager is able to access the 2nd manager's employee detail after changing the url for ex. http://0.0.0.0:3000/leave_details/238/edit    this is url if i change id 238 to 100 it is a Accessible .. but it shold not be ..

Comment: its not an issue with the sessions. You have to filter the employers by their relation with the manager, i.e., if the manager is logged in, you do:
current_user.employers.find(params[:id])
or
Employer.joins(:manager).where("manager.id = ?", current_user.id)